# UITabBarController with 5 identical UITablesViewControllers - how to implement with storyBoard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I am working on a todo app with storyboard and want to implement this scenario:

My root controller is a tabbar.

I have five tab bars buttons: today tomorrow and future and two others - each holds a UINavigationController that leads to a UITableViewController.

The thing is all five are identical in implementation and the only difference between them is their data.

My question is how do i implement this scenario with storyboards?

Comment: You can set the same class to every tab bar item and in the implementation verify what's the name of the "item", or do another kind of verification...

Comment: do i have to keep 5 different identical UITableViewController?

Comment: you can use baritem tag to check different condition while loading the table data

Answer (score 0):

Into your storyboard, you must create three (or more) UIViewControllers (or UITableViewControllers) that are connected with the `Tab Bar Controller`, like here:
[image: Example 01]

All of the three `tableView cells` must have the same `cell identifier`:
[image: Example 02]

And you need to set the same class to every `UIViewController` (or `UITableViewController` - I assume that the class is called `FirstViewController`):
[image: Example 03]

Finally, you need to select the tableViews and set the tag differently:
[image: Example 04]
[image]

Now let's go to the code. In your FirstViewController.h (or another class name), add the tableView delegate and data source methods:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([tableView tag] == 0) {

        // today table
        return [todayArray count];

    }else if ([tableView tag] == 1) {

        // tomorrow table
        return [tomorrow count];

    } else if ([tableView tag] == 2) {

        // future table
        return [future count];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([tableView tag] == 0) {
        // today table
        // Do something with the today tableView

    }else if ([tableView tag] == 1) {
        // tomorrow table
        // Do something with the tomorrow tableView

    } else if ([tableView tag] == 2) {
        // future table
        // Do something with the future tableView
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this help you, and make you solve the question...

Comment: tnx. is passing all the data to all controllers is the best practice? and if i have more viewControllers coming out *of* each tableViewController (like detailsViewController) - again, there is duplication..

Comment: If you'll have detailViewControllers you can make the verification inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`: `if ([tableView tag] == 0) { // push the detail from the first tableView }`.